# Android : Effective way to write JsonArray in File

Tags: android, json, file, filewriter

I have some Problem with  Writing JsonArray in file.When I Use

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile));      
out.writeObject(jarr);
```

It throw error

```
 java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.gson.JsonArray
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at com.example.calljavascript.MainActivity.copyFile(MainActivity.java:281)
    at com.example.calljavascript.MainActivity.onResultRecived(MainActivity.java:191)
    at com.example.calljavascript.JavaScriptInterface.receiveValueFromJs(JavaScriptInterface.java:32)
    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have also tried

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(destFile);
file.write(jarr.toString());
```

through `FileWriter` , We can just write `jsonobject`. Since I have got from almost source. We can write jsonarray after `toString()`, And I cann't use `toString()` to write `Jsonarray`. Becuase after `toString()` , I cannot use that json file futher, what's problem ? I can't get it.

I have also tried it through `ByteArrayInputStream` after converting jsonarray to bytearray, but doesn't get any success to read that json file.

**Please Tell me an Effective way to write JsonArray, Where No need to use `toString()`**

Comment: After toString, you can't use the file futher?

Comment: @Olayinka, I have some NDK tools which is read that json file , error are thrown from there.I have only .so FIle (compilation of  c/c++ class) not that c  and c++ class , So i can't get error there.

Comment: Andrioid JSON API always works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GSON, you could make use of the [GSON Stream APIs](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html?com/google/gson/stream/package-summary.html) to write to and read from file.

Comment: That link is broken. Please provide code snippets in your answer rather than just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Just as your logcat trace said `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.gson.JsonArray`, `JsonArray` doesn't implement `Serializable`, so `out.writeObject(jarr);` can't be run. And when you call `JsonArray.toString()`, the result of `String` implements `Serializable`. And `JsonArray` **DO** have the method of `toString` which is inherited from `Object`. You can call `out.writeObject(jarr.toString());` to write a `JsonArray` into a `File`.

Comment: he already tried toString and it didn't help since he has to read the file back into an object.

Comment: Then you have to set your `Object` you want to write into a file implementing `Serializable`, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works for me:

```
UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential();
    credentials.Subscriber = subscriber;
    credentials.Email = email;
    credentials.Password = password;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(credentials);
    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(CredentialsFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(json.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Credentials error ", e.getMessage());
    }
```